# python - sorting a sequence with key function

Tags: python, list

It is unclear to me how the following works:

```
In [1]: student_tuples = [('john', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10)]
In [2]: sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])
Out [2]: [('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)] # sort by age
```

but,

```
In [3]: st = lambda student: student[2]
In [4]: st(student_tuples)
Out [4]: ('dave', 'B', 10)
```

Why does the `[2]` in the former sample refer to the index for the individual tuples, when in a lambda function it returns the 2nd tuple in the list?

Comment: It refers to item 2 of whatever the function is called on. You're not calling it on what `sorted` calls it on.

Comment: A key function is applied to each element individually, not the iterable as a whole.  You can, for example, sort by absolute value, even though lists don't have an absolute value.  `sorted([1, 2, -3], key=abs)`

Comment: `sorted` function is iterable:

`help(sorted)` provides:
> `sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)`
> Return a new list containing all items from the iterable in ascending order.

Answer (score 5):

Because when you're sorting, the key function is called once for every element of the list being sorted. That's why it's `lambda student:` not `lambda student_tuples:` (not that the naming of parameters changes anything, just explaining the naming choice).

You can see this directly by printing the argument of the key function:

```
student_tuples = [('john', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10)]

def my_key(student):
    print(student)
    return student[2]

sorted(student_tuples, key=my_key)
# calls to my_key print:
# ('john', 'A', 15)
# ('jane', 'B', 12)
# ('dave', 'B', 10)

my_key(student_tuples)
# prints (not returns):
# [('john', 'A', 15), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('dave', 'B', 10)]
```