# Why is the Python code output like this? (lambda function involved)

Tags: python, lambda

I have found a code that orders the elements of a list according to the grades specifid in the tuples that constitute the list.
I cannot understand how it works though: shouldn't be specified somewhere that the parameter data is referred to the students list?
Thanks

```
students = [("Squidwaard", "F", 60),
        ("Sandy", "A", 33),
        ("Patrick", "D", 36),
        ("Spongebob", "B", 20),
        ("Mr.Krabs", "C", 78)]

grade = lambda data: data[1]
students.sort(key=grade)

for i in students:
    print(i)
```

Comment: It is sorting using data[1] specified in the lambda function I believe.

Comment: `data` is just the function argument of the function `grade`. You can define `grade = lambda x: x[1]` and get the same result. In python, a lambda function is no different than a non-lambda function (which is defined using `def`) except that a  lambda function is shorter and can be written in one line of code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - sorting a sequence with key function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223227/python-sorting-a-sequence-with-key-function)

Comment: "shouldn't be specified somewhere that the parameter data is referred to the students list?" Yes, and it is - by the fact that it's a parameter to the `sort` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here you did specify in your code. You have wrote a function (anonymous) and called in `students.sort(key=grade)` what key does is use the function given to sort it by. So you are sorting by the 1st index element, which is the letter grade. Hope this helped, have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [answer] and avoid conversational language in answers (and questions), as this is *not a discussion forum*.